# Old user removed, now having DEFINER errors

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Old users were removed from the `mysql.user` table and now while running some views, I got the error that the user@host does not exist. Also while taking a dump, a view is unable to be dumped due to user not existing. I have been researching on the best way to update definers when I remove an old user from the `mysql.user` table. Of course, the old users were DEFINERS in one view, or sp. A quick fix I did was to take a dump of the db with a regex that removes the definers from the dump file and restore the db - this way the new definer will be the user performing the restore operation.
Also I found 2 other ways online (https://www.adminbirds.com/mysql/how-to-change-the-definer-for-views/) - I need to verify this method.

1. to change definers in views: `SELECT CONCAT("ALTER DEFINER=`youruser`@`host`VIEW ", table_name, " AS ", view_definition, ";") FROM information_schema.views WHERE table_schema='your-database-name';` this will generate the alter statement for manually changing the definer in the `information_schema.views` table.
2. To change definers in store procedures: `UPDATE`mysql`.`proc`p SET definer = 'user@%' WHERE definer='root@%'` this will manually change the definer in the `mysql.proc` table. Although I read from MySQL doc page that `It is not supported that the server will notice manual manipulation of this table.`

So here is my question: If I run the above commands, will it affect the data? Is it safe to run? I know the `ALTER` statement only affects structure, but just want to be sure, since I will be running this in a prod environment as well. The `UPDATE` statement definitely changes the data in the `mysql.proc` table and I need to be sure this is safe to proceed. Please advise.

Comment: Why not drop and recreate the objects under the desired schema/

Answer (score 0):

as You can see from text of both commands - they not work with data other than single table, so from this point of view - both safe.

In worst case - You already have not worked views and continue have them :), but it not expected result.

But, **in any case** - the best practice - **make backup before** any kind of similar operations, so You always can rollback.

Notice in server documentation:

> The server manipulates the mysql.proc table in response to statements
>   that  create, alter, or drop stored routines. It is not supported that
>   the  server will notice manual manipulation of this table.

more related to other types of manipulation, like - manual edit of BLOB object with text or parameters, but change definer - it just change single column.

Comment: Thanks a_vlad for your response. I also found that none of the commands actually change the definers in TRIGGERS. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: for triggers - only dump with --triggers option and replace definer, than restore, it is as I know.

Answer (score 0):

My quick fix was to create new users with the old usernames.